# Objective C: Force Usage of Getters and Setters?

Tags: objective-c, setter, getter

I've noticed that often times when I create a custom getter/setter for a property in Objective C, at least once somewhere in my class, I forget to use `self.variableName` to access my property and instead access it directly with just `variableName`, which defeats the purpose of the getter and setter (and may cause a bug later on that could be tough to track down).

Now, the obvious solution to this is problem is "stop forgetting to include `self.`"

However, is there a way to remove direct access to the instance variable (perhaps when declaring the property?) to avoid the accidental non-usage of getters and setters?

Don't get me wrong, sometimes it is nice to be able to access instance variables directly and avoid the getters and setters, but sometimes when I write a custom getter and setter, it is important that these getters and setters get used every time and do not get forgotten.

Again, the obvious answer is just to remember to use `self.`, but especially if somebody else is picking up my code and working on it, it would be beneficial to completely remove access to the instance variable in some situations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use instance variables prefixed with `_`. It's what Apple recommends, it's what the synthesize-properties-and-invent-instance-variables-by-default feature does and it makes the `_` stick out when you use them. It's not possible inside your own implementation to remove access to your own instance variables.

Comment: Hmm okay.  That's probably a good idea.  At least the user has to consciously make a choice to access the instance variable instead of accessing the instance variable being the default.  Doesn't Apple frown on underscore notation though, or is it considered "okay" now?

Comment: Underscore notation for instance variables has always been okay, even more so now with the modern runtime where the instance variables for each class are insulated. If I have an `a` ivar and inherit from someone with an `a` ivar, I can't trample it. You're thinking of underscore-prefix methods/messages that very much live in the same namespace.

Comment: Awesome, thanks.  I'm not particularly a fan of underscore notation, but I now see why it has it's place and I will likely use it in some circumstances.